# Ubuntu 20.04 - Verifying 5.8.3 Kernel

Tags: kernel, sha256sum

I have a Lenovo+Ryzen-4500 laptop running 20.04 that needs a later Kernel for external monitors. I installed 5.8.0 some weeks back and it has been working fine for me. I just read about an FBI report on a rogue Kernel thing and thought I'd update the kernel.

Kernel 5.8.3 is now available and I have downloaded all 4 .deb files from here
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/)

But cannot figure out how to use the SHA256 checksum on the .deb files. That link gives a checksum for a single file/bundle and not the .deb ones.

Could someone please give me some steps on achieving this verification before installing this update for the current 5.8.0.

Comment: the individual checksums are in a subdirectory from that page, [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/CHECKSUMS).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to securely download a new kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142488/how-to-securely-download-a-new-kernel)